# getting a number from a user and making changes and turning it into a string

Tags: java, string, int, tostring

I am making a math program that guesses the birthday of the user.

The user enters a number lets say : 75622 and i subtract a number from it to get the birthday, in this case 42682 -- 04/26/82

i want to be able to turn that integer into a string and then add the forward slash between the month, day and year.. and also add a 0 if it is only 5 digits and not 6 ( because of the month being 1-9).

I know how to use Integer.toString(int) to turn it into a string, but i do not know how to insert the forward slashes and the zero.

thank you kindly!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to convert the `int` to a `String` (with a leading `0`) you can use `String.format` like

```
int num = 42682;
String s = String.format("%06d", num);
```

You might then use another `String.format` and `String.substring` to build your desired output, like

```
String output = String.format("%s/%s/%s", s.substring(0, 2), 
        s.substring(2, 4), s.substring(4));
System.out.println(output);
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
04/26/82
```

Comment: Or just `printf("%02d/%02d/%02d", num / 10000, num / 100 % 100, num % 100)`

Comment: i gotta use joptionpane

Answer (score 1):

Please find answer below:

```
public class CreateDateFromNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 42682;
        System.out.println(getDate(number));
    }

    public static String getDate(int number) {
        String numberStr = Integer.toString(number);
        String outputStr = "";

        if (numberStr.length() != 5 && numberStr.length() != 6) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Number should be length of 5 or 6");
        }

        if (numberStr.length() == 5) {
            numberStr = "0" + numberStr;
        }

        int var0 = 0;

        while (var0 < numberStr.length()) {
            String var1 = numberStr.substring(var0, var0 + 2);
            outputStr = outputStr + var1;

            if (var0 + 2 < numberStr.length()) {
                outputStr = outputStr + "/";
            }
            var0 = var0 + 2;
        }
        return outputStr;
    }

}
```